# Getting Parent Fragment as null, how to fix it?

Tags: android-fragments

I have five tabs,within that, one tab contains multiple tabs i am trying to load that tab data,first time that data is loading,next-time on wards  not loading the data.i was debugged,getting parent fragment as null.Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: post some code and the error Log

Comment: Welcome to So, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask